# Sendmail refuses to sign messages with DKIM provided by opendkim

Tags: sendmail, dkim, opendkim

I have sendmail and opendkim installed on ubuntu 14.04 and would like to configure DKIM.

Unfortunately sendmail refuses to sign outgoing emails with DKIM. Despite the fact that it already did before, but I commented it due to the fact that I did have to wait for DNS-entries to list the TXT-Record. Now I outcommented it, rebuild sendmail config and restarted sendmail and opendkim, but mail-tester.com claims that the messages are not signed.

Here is the entry for sendmail.mc:

```
INPUT_MAIL_FILTER(`opendkim', `S=local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock')dnl
```

check socket:

```
/etc/mail$ ll /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock 
srwxrwxr-x 1 opendkim opendkim 0 Jan  9 03:07 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock=
```

These are the log entries from mail.log at log_level 15

```
sm-mta[26489]: NOQUEUE: connect from localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
AUTH: available mech=DIGEST-MD5 NTLM CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS, allowed mech=EXTERNAL GSSAPI KERBEROS_V4 DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
Milter (opendkim): init success to negotiate
Milter: connect to filters
milter=opendkim, action=connect, continue
--- 220 my-server-adress ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4.1ubuntu1; Tue, 12 Jan 2016 17:35:35 +0100; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost.localdomain(OK)-localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
<-- EHLO my-server-adress
--- 250-my-server-adress Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
--- 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
--- 250-PIPELINING
--- 250-EXPN
--- 250-VERB
--- 250-8BITMIME
--- 250-SIZE
--- 250-DSN
--- 250-ETRN
--- 250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
--- 250-DELIVERBY
--- 250 HELP
<-- MAIL From:<my-sender-email> SIZE=6179 AUTH=my-sender-email
ruleset=trust_auth, arg1=my-sender-email, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], reject=550 5.7.1 <my-sender-email>... not authenticated
Milter: sender: <my-sender-email>
milter=opendkim, action=mail, continue
--- 250 2.1.0 <my-sender-email>... Sender ok
<-- RCPT To:<recipient-email-adress
Milter: rcpts: <recipient-email-adress
milter=opendkim, action=rcpt, continue
--- 250 2.1.5 <recipient-email-adress... Recipient ok
<-- DATA
--- 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
from=<my-sender-email>, size=6272, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<2c90803085a92272e055dd342339854e@www.findix.at>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
milter=opendkim, action=header, continue
message repeated 10 times: [ milter=opendkim, action=header, continue]
milter=opendkim, action=eoh, continue
milter=opendkim, action=body, continue
Milter insert (1): header: DKIM-Signature:  v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=findix.com; s=dkim;\n\tt=1452616535; bh=lL6Nxp+zwlmTE0SjCbctUgyFK/k+y3VgD/s/9XraXGU=;\n\th=To:Subject:Date:From:From;\n\tb=BJAqA5Cp/Koy67VAQ7KVDN6RXeu1P9imkRxprNn/uInAK6PCLDsGZGzr05S4oM4qs\n\t GONufC0GLu/eZYUNKBHoVfSkC6e5x99erbufkSGfLVrHlxCpRCRplr7P9lOwc1+3pF\n\t ImvRO2d+Gy2+OqFPydAb77blcxTsNb82VMS9HgwE=
Milter accept: message
poststats: /var/lib/sendmail/sendmail.st: No such file or directory
--- 250 2.0.0 u0CGZZpo026489 Message accepted for delivery
```

Mail.err does not show any problems. What else could I check to get it running? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What is reported by opendkim in `mail.info` or `mail.log`?

Comment: there seems to be nothing despite sendmails entries inside mail.log: Jan 11 11:50:27 fx2 sendmail[10843]: u0BAoRFV010843: to=<web-sU9hLu@mail-tester.com>, ctladdr=myemail (1000/100), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30114, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u0BAoRko010844 Message accepted for delivery)
Jan 11 11:50:27 fx2 sm-mta[10846]: u0BAoRko010844: to=<web-sU9hLu@mail-tester.com>, ctladdr=<myemail> (1000/100), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120361, relay=mail-tester.com. [94.23.206.89], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 123B49FB33)

Comment: Have you compiled `sendmail.mc` into `sendmail.cf`?  It may explain missing log entries.

Comment: yes, I did a "make" inside the dir and a reload of sendmail

Comment: What happens if you increase Sendmail logging? What events show up? Specifically, milter interaction events?

Comment: I have added the entries to the question with log level 15

Comment: According to the log the message is signed. Apparently, some other mechanism is later removing the signature. Needs further debugging.